# Freeform Next - Questions About Dynamic Notification Recipients

Tags: solspace-freeform-next

I have a job application form set up that will need to alert a few people by default (owner and admin assistant).  I have those set up in the form settings, under Notify -> Admin Recipients.  The job recruiter (which varies among the jobs) also needs to be notified.  So I'd like to set this in the template using

```
dynamic_notification_recipients="{recruiter_email}"
```

and set my template

```
dynamic_notification_template="test.html"
```

My questions:

- Setting it up this way, will both the "Admin Recipients" (those to receive it by default) and the recruiter be notified?
- Is the template that I need to refer to one that I set up via the "Email Templates" settings (similar to the ones I did under Formatting Templates)?
- Does just the recruiter receive the email using the TEST template, while the "Admin Recipients" receive the default notification that is referenced in the form settings?  Or does this override that setting, and everyone get an email using the TEST template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing, the answers are as follows:

- Yes both the people in the "Admin Recipients" and the people listed via the overrides will receive notifications.
- Yes, the template will be set up via "Email Templates" in the general Form settings area.
- The people listed in the overrides will be notified via the template that is set via the overrides setting.  The people listed in the "Admin Recipients" setting in the individual form will be notified via the form listed in that setting.  This could be the same template.